# Read-only vnc connection to an existing X11 session

Tags: linux, xorg, vnc, remote

I need to allow people to view (but not affect) my X11 session remotely.

tightvncserver has a read-only password, but doesn't work with existing sessions.

x11vnc works with existing sessions, but doesn't have a read-only option.

Is there a free solution for Linux that has both features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the manual helped. x11vnc has an option `-viewonly`, which is exactly what I need.